# Strange scenario Convert.ToChar(integer) or (char)integer

Tags: c#

I have the following condition.

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(65)); // Gives 'A'

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(65) + 1); // Gives 66; Expectation was 'A1'

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(65) + "1"); // Gives 'A1'
```

Why is that? I wanted the 3rd case.

Comment: As you are adding an int, the char A was implicitly converted to int

Comment: Another option is `Convert.ToChar(65).ToString() + 1`  If one of the values in an addition is a `string` then it will `ToString` the other value and concatenate.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the question title and body if it does not look appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

Reason you are getting 66 instead of A1 is because you are adding a char to an integer. If you add a string to char, only then it will return you a string.

> [documentation on char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/x9h8tsay(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) The char keyword is used to declare an instance of the System.Char structure that the .NET Framework uses to represent a Unicode character. The value of a Char object is a 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value

Comment: That first statement is a bit misleading.  `Convert.ToChar(65)` does produce `A`, but as a `char` not a `string` which is what the _and when you add something to a string, it is "appended" to it_ seems to imply.

Comment: @juharr removed the statement and left the documentation that explains the effect there

Answer (score 5):

Your expectation is wrong. The `char` type is a numeric type and can hold  whole numbers. So when you do

```
Convert.ToChar(65)
```

you still have a number with the value 65. So when you do

```
Convert.ToChar(65) +1
```

You are implicitly converting the char back to an int and adding +1 thus you get 66

The special thing about char which distinguishes it from other number types is, when you convert it to string, it gets displayed as the "characters" we know from the alphabet. Thus, when you do

```
Convert.ToChar(65) + "1"
```

The char with value 65 is implicitly converted to a string (`"A"`) and then concatenated with the string `"1"`. Thus the result is `"A1"`

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators):

> In the case of integral types, those operators (except the `++` and `--` operators) are defined for the `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong` types. When operands are of other integral types (`sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, or `char`), their values are converted to the `int` type, which is also the result type of an operation.

So in your second case, `Convert.ToChar(65)` gives `'A'`, but `'A' + 1` forces `'A'` to the `int` type, which gives `65 + 1`, which is `66`.

Since `string` isn't an integral type, the `+` operator for that class is defined to append the character to the string, and you get the string `"A1"`.

Answer (score 3):

**First Case:**

`Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(65));`

Above case is giving you result as `A`, because it is using [`Console.WriteLine(char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Char_) function.

---

**Second Case**

As per [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/x9h8tsay(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#conversions):

> A char can be implicitly converted to ushort, **int**, uint, long, ulong,
> float, double, or decimal.

> **Note:** *string* type is not mentioned in the above implicit conversion list.

In your second example, the compiler is converting `Convert.ToChar(65)` i.e `'A'` to integer **implicitly** and adding 1 to it and giving the result as `66` not `A1`

---

**Third case**

In your third example, you are concatenating char `'A'` with string `"1"` using [`+` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings#-and--operators) which is printing `"A1"` as a string to the console.